# How to fix an image downloading/saving error on Android

Tags: android, url, bitmap, android-asynctask, inputstream

I am programming an Android application where I fetch a number of images off the internet to display in a gallery. The images are first saved to disk before they are fetched by fragments inside a ViewPager set to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The problem I have is that after the third image is downloaded, any image afterwards causes a NullPointerException, where the URL is apparently null. Here is the downloadBitmap() method I use:

```
    static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient
            .newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                    + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
        // IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from "
                + url);
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Again, after the third image is downloaded, the method begins to spit out errors that state "Error while retrieving bitmap from" without an URL appended to the end, implying that I am passing null or blank strings to the method. However, this is not the case, as logging the URL string I pass right before the method is run using Log.d("URL", saidURL) indicates that the URLs are perfectly valid. The downloadBitmap() code is called in the following AsyncTask.

```
    class RetrieveImagesTask extends
        AsyncTask<ArrayList<Magazine>, String, ArrayList<Magazine>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Magazine> doInBackground(
            ArrayList<Magazine>... arg0) {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        for (Magazine mag : arg0[0]) {
            if (!new File(filesDir, mag.ID + ".jpg").exists())
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filesDir + mag.ID
                            + ".jpg");
                    Log.d("URL", mag.imageURL);
                    bitmap = downloadBitmap(mag.imageURL);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return arg0[0];
    }
```

Any help with this strange state of affairs? Could it possibly be a problem with running out of memory?

Comment: Could please post the exception details by changing the catch part to `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Turns out the server I was fetching the URLs from was feeding me empty URL strings half the time.

Answer (score -1):

```
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient
        .newInstance("Android");
final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
        return null;
    }

    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();


            final Bitmap bitmap;

 int h = 100; // height in pixels
                int w = 100; // width in pixels
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(inputStream), h, w, true);

            return bitmap;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
    // IllegalStateException
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from "
            + url);
} finally {
    if (client != null) {
        client.close();
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: Please try to add and explanation to this code